# WordPress Admin Bar Moving Links

Tags: admin-bar

Is there a way to move the links such as Add New Appearance Comments into one menu

Comment: This post http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4998/is-the-new-wordpress-3-1-admin-bar-pluggable-and-how-can-i-extend-it may be helpful in understanding the innards of the bar, and making edits

Answer (score 8):

### Unset

Here's an **example** of how to unset the comments link if the default status is 'closed' (offers 2 different approaches).

```
/**
 * Disable 'Comments' link if default status is _closed_
 */
function remove_comments() 
{
    $default_comment_status = get_option( 'default_comment_status' );

    if ( $default_comment_status == 'closed' ) 
    {
        remove_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_comments_menu', 50 );

        // optional solution using the WP_Admin_Bar class from /wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php
        # global $wp_admin_bar;
        # $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'comments' );
    }
    else 
    {
        return;
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'remove_comments', 0 );
```

You can use `remove_action` calls for any of the following (/wp-includes/class.admin-bar.php - line 182 - 192) to unset the menu items:

```
function remove_all_admin_bar_items() 
{
    remove_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_my_account_menu', 10 );
    remove_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_my_sites_menu', 20 );
    remove_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_edit_menu', 30 );
    remove_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_shortlink_menu', 80 );
    remove_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_updates_menu', 70 );

    if ( !is_network_admin() && !is_user_admin() ) {
        remove_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_new_content_menu', 40 );
        remove_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_comments_menu', 50 );
        remove_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_appearance_menu', 60 );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'remove_all_admin_bar_items', 0 );
```

---

### Set and re-order

Add the following calls to your `functions.php` file **after** unsetting the items. The integer at the end of every `add_action` call is the new "order".

```
function reorder_admin_bar_items()
{
    add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_my_account_menu', 100 );
    add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_my_sites_menu', 10 );
    add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_edit_menu', 40 );
    add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_shortlink_menu', 20 );
    add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_updates_menu', 50 );

    if ( !is_network_admin() && !is_user_admin() ) {
        add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_new_content_menu', 80 );
        add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_comments_menu', 170 );
        add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_appearance_menu', 40 );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'reorder_admin_bar_items', 20 );
```

---

### Add a single item & sub menu item

You can also use the `add_admin_bar_menus` hook to add items to your admin bar.

```
function parent_menu_item() 
    {
        global $wp_admin_bar;

        // Parent
        $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( 
            array( 
                 'id'       => 'parent_id_name'
                ,'title'    => __( 'Parent Title', 'your_textdomain' )
                ,'href'     => '#'
            ) 
        );
            // Link to dev mode admin page
            $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( 
                array( 
                     'parent'   => 'parent_id_name'
                    ,'id'           => 'child_id_name'
                    ,'title'    => __( 'Child title', 'your_textdomain' )
                    ,'href'     => '#'
                ) 
            );
    }
    add_action( 'add_admin_bar_menus', 'parent_menu_item', 10 );
```

I can't think of how to make this guide more complete, but anybody can feel free to edit my answer and add everything that could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to "move" - you must unset the item and add new to your structure in the Admin Bar. See the link from the answer on Rays comment.