# WP 3.3 How to Add Menu Items to the Admin Bar?

Tags: plugin-development

[image]I've just installed the Yoast SEO plugin and noticed that a new flyout menu was added to the admin bar once the plugin was activated.

Anyone know is there is a tutorial or example on how this is done?

Comment: A couple of related questions that may be of interest, [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/12502/1468) and [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/4998/1468).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The action hook `admin_bar_menu` does the job. Here's what the comment in the core file says:

> It includes the action "admin_bar_menu" which should be used to hook
>   in and add new menus to the admin bar. That way you can be sure that
>   you are adding at most optimal point, right before the admin bar is
>   rendered. This also gives you access to the $post global, among
>   others.

Usage:

```
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'add_items');

function add_items($admin_bar)
{
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($admin_bar);
//echo "<pre>";

$admin_bar->add_menu( array(
    'id'    => 'my-item',
            'parent' => 'top-secondary',
    'title' => 'My Item',
    'href'  => '#',
    'meta'  => array(
        'title' => __('My Item'),
    ),
) );
}
```

You're gonna have to tweak a bit with it, because this code added the new item to the extreme left! I think examining the `$admin_bar` variable should give you an idea how to add an item.

**Update:** `'parent' => 'top-secondary'` adds the item on the left of 'Howdy...'! So I bet there are other such position values. I'm looking for them ;)

**Update 2:** `'parent' => 'new-content'` adds the item in the `New > Post, Media` etc menu.

**Update 3:** `'parent' => 'wp-logo-external'` adds the item in the menu popped out from the WordPress logo on the extreme left.

**UPDATE:**

I have written a [blog post](http://blog.rutwick.com/add-items-anywhere-to-the-wp-3-3-admin-bar) with all possible positions for the new item in the admin bar menu... If anyone interested please [read here](http://blog.rutwick.com/add-items-anywhere-to-the-wp-3-3-admin-bar).

Comment: +1 Thanks. Adding 100,100 at the end of the action moves it to the right of the core menus.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the 100, 100 thing! I was wondering how to do that. Btw, I'm looking for more such position values, look for the updates in my answer ;)